# Fastest function returning 0?

Tags: python, performance

In a runtime distribution I just saw the fastest submission used `defaultdict(lambda: 0)`. Instead of the typical `defaultdict(int)`. So I wondered whether that's faster and what's the fastest equivalent function (i.e. returns `0` when called without arguments). Turns out it's slower and I did find a faster one, but is there something even faster?

Benchmark results (on [tio.run](https://tio.run/##dU9Na8MwDL3nV@gyIpVSUrLDCPSXlGG8RdkMsWNsb6SU/vZMtrv1NF0snp/eh7@kz8X1Lz5s2xQWC8lYNgmM9UtIENizTk0zfbn3CCc4NyDTGpfafV1nbd9GPUD3C3RwUEoISgnyKqdLgHwOxpU3DoW3ihp/6xkzRkgF1DGyuKaLZ1wJTJSjBNqNmX6CrqqpLBW0@2Dsqar9Y5InF8rRo/ThEWsjfFgT/VF9EDuc2mv@GK5Wr2i1x5ndvqoS3W73no/ZYQtPz4fjBC7KBphgB0fuqaRKOVLJcDeqJrRtPw)):

```
int         46.3 ns  46.4 ns  46.6 ns  46.8 ns  46.8 ns
lambda: 0   69.9 ns  70.1 ns  70.4 ns  70.5 ns  71.0 ns
0 .__int__  36.4 ns  36.5 ns  36.5 ns  36.6 ns  36.9 ns
```

At LeetCode (where I saw that that runtime distribution and solution):

```
int         31.6 ns  31.6 ns  31.6 ns  32.3 ns  32.5 ns
lambda: 0   51.5 ns  51.5 ns  51.7 ns  52.6 ns  53.1 ns
0 .__int__  27.0 ns  27.0 ns  27.0 ns  27.0 ns  27.0 ns
```

On my laptop:

```
int         124.7 ns  124.8 ns  125.4 ns  125.7 ns  125.9 ns
lambda: 0   222.4 ns  222.7 ns  222.7 ns  223.3 ns  224.4 ns
0 .__int__  112.0 ns  112.1 ns  112.1 ns  112.3 ns  112.7 ns
```

Benchmark code:

```
from timeit import repeat

funcs = [
    'int',
    'lambda: 0',
    '0 .__int__',
]

for func in funcs:
    x = eval(func)()
    assert type(x) is int and x == 0

for _ in range(3):
    for func in funcs:
        times = sorted(repeat(eval(func)))
        print(f'{func:{max(map(len, funcs))}}',
              *(' %4.1f ns' % (t * 1e3) for t in times))
    print()
```

Comment: I think you should not use CPython if you really care about such micro-optimization. Having a function call is the main problem here and CPython does not perform this optimization. I strongly advise you to use Cython (or Numba), or even a native language is you really need high-performance (note that you can just write one optimized function called from Python). A call of a function returning 0 that is not inlined in C/C++ should take not more than 1-3 ns on a mainstream processor.  This is 10 times faster. When inlined, the cost is close to 0.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Does LeetCode support Cython/Numba?

Comment: I do not know about this specific platform but most similar platform does not (unfortunately) support external modules. But they are designed so all problems can be solved without (advanced) micro-optimization (such like this). *Algorithms* are the key to get performant code on such platforms. Thus, to me the question looks like an XY problem. You could explain the more general problem you are trying to solve (not the sub-problem certainly caused by your chosen algorithm/approach). Btw, LeetCode supports C++ at least ;) .

Comment: @JérômeRichard Well, sometimes I try to microoptimize to get the best time in a speed ranking. Did so 24 years ago at acm.uva.es, sometimes still do it today (not on LeetCode, that system is way too unstable, plus there are no speed rankings with people's names). Not trying to find the fastest way to solve a problem, but for example the fastest Python solution (the rankings don't mix languages, so it's irrelevant that another language is faster). This feels similar, though perhaps less significant/meaningful than for example `operator.truth` being faster than `bool`.

Comment: Are you just asking out of curiosity? (and not specifically to make Python on LeetCode run faster than C++, which is a lost cause)